# Failing to connect MQ with java 11

Tags: ibm-mq, java-11

After upgrading to JDK 11 from JDK 8 and MQ 9.2.0.5 (from 9.2.0.4), i'm getting the below error when trying to open JMS connection.

I'm running on WLS 14.

I also upgraded allclient.jar to 9.2.0.5.

I tried running it with previous MQ (9.2.0.4) which worked fine with java 8, i get the same issue.
Same code works fine with MQ 9.2.0.4, JDK 8 and WLS 12.

I verified that method exists in jar and verified no other versions of allclient jars exists.

> com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code
> received.
> [1=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment,
> int)],3=Class.getConstructor0]
> at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:857)
> at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:702)
> at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8437)
> at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
> at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:322)
> at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:242)
> at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6026)
> at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6086)
> at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.doCreateConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:188)
> at . Caused by: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment,
> int)**
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
> at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:764)

Comment: What JDK are you using? IBM, AdoptOpenJDK, Oracle, etc?

Comment: java 11.0.10 2021-01-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)

Comment: If I had to guess, I would suspect that you have mixed and matched versions of the IBM MQ client jars.  I'd check to see where the IBM client jars are deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove if you have com.ibm.* related packages in prefer-application-packages section in weblogic.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a couple of Java/JMS applications using OpenJDK 11 and they ran fine.  I agree with Doug Grove that you probably have a mismatch of MQ JAR files.

Add the following line to your code and then update your question with the output:

```
System.out.println("java.class.path="+System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

If you want to get fancy then you can do:

```
if (null != System.getProperty("java.class.path"))
{
   if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows"))
      System.out.println("java.class.path=\n"+(System.getProperty("java.class.path")).replace(';', '\n'));
   else
      System.out.println("java.class.path\n="+(System.getProperty("java.class.path")).replace(':', '\n'));
}
```